# Python: Get single signal from ipywidgets.observe() rather than 3

Tags: python, ipywidgets, object.observe

Essentially, I am creating a number of Toggle Buttons using ipywidgets. When the button is clicked, I would like to add an element to a list. If the button is unclicked, the element is to be removed. (I have not gotten to the action yet)

For the Toggle Button, I am using `.observe()` and find that each time I press a button, I am returned 3 signals. `{False, True, True}` if clicked and `{True, False, False}` if unclicked. I think `.observe()` is running 3 times each time there is a button click. Is there any way to return just one signal or is there an error with my code?

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
test = np.array(['test1','test2'])
def buttonArray(button_list):
    switch = [widgets.ToggleButton(description = name, value = False) for name in button_list]
    combined = widgets.HBox(switch)
    display(combined)    

    def upon_clicked(btn):
        signal = btn.owner.value
        print(signal)

    for n in range(len(button_list)):
        switch[n].observe(upon_clicked)

buttonArray(test)
```

See image for output when a button is pressed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `print(btn)` in the observed function you will see that the function is being run three times. You aren't getting an array of three values, it is a function that produces a single value being run three times:

```
{'name': '_property_lock', 'old': traitlets.Undefined, 'new': {'value': True}, 'owner': ToggleButton(value=False, description='test1'), 'type': 'change'}

{'name': 'value', 'old': False, 'new': True, 'owner': ToggleButton(value=True, description='test1'), 'type': 'change'}

{'name': '_property_lock', 'old': {'value': True}, 'new': {}, 'owner': ToggleButton(value=True, description='test1'), 'type': 'change'}
```

The `_property_lock` attribute is being changed twice, and the the `value` attribute once in the middle, hence the three function calls.

In most cases, you probably just want the middle set data. To achieve this, you need to state the `name` values that get passed to the observed function, in this case `names=['value']`:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
test = np.array(['test1','test2'])
def buttonArray(button_list):
    switch = [widgets.ToggleButton(description = name, value = False) for name in button_list]
    combined = widgets.HBox(switch)
    display(combined)    

    def upon_clicked(btn):
        print(btn)
        signal = btn.owner.value
#         print(signal)

    for n in range(len(button_list)):
        switch[n].observe(upon_clicked, names=['value'])  # CHANGED HERE

buttonArray(test)
```